# Unable to fetch values from _EnterpriseAttribute Data view

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views

I want to import the members of the List to a Data extension.
The required fields are EmailAddress, SubscriberKey and FirstName.

I was able to get the EmailAddress and SubscriberKey  from the **_ListSubscribers** Data view.

But to fetch the attribute value, I am trying to use the **_EnterpriseAttribute**

But I am facing the below issue.
[image]

Comment: Two caveats... you have to be an Enterprise 2.0 client and this view is only accessible from the parent BU

Comment: you may need to add ENT. in front on _enterpriseattribute

Comment: Thanks @EazyE  I confirm that the above query was correct and worked fine in other client account...... I hope this account is NOT a Enterprise 2.0 ... Below is the screenshot of my account type... https://pasteboard.co/IIKlYB6.png

Answer (score 1):

Try running it with the `ENT.` prefix:

> In order to combine the data about your subscribers kept in the
>   Profile Attributes with any of the Data Views, you will need to join
>   them on SubscriberID with the EnterpriseAttribute data view. If you
>   are running your query outside the parent business unit, it has to be
>   used with the ENT. prefix.

Like this:

```
ENT._EnterpriseAttribute
```

Read more: [Data Views](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/)

Comment: Thanks @zuzannamj...... however I am still facing the below error message....Errors: The 'Ent.' prefix can only be used to query data in a parent account from a child account. ENT._EnterpriseAttribute is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views.

Comment: I am NOT confident that my account is 2.0..... it shows as below.... https://pasteboard.co/IIBjYfn.png

Comment: are you able to query other data views, like _Sent?

Comment: Do brackets help? Like [ENT._EnterpriseAttribute] or [_EnterpriseAttribute]?

Comment: Even I tried the above backets and did not help :(........ @ZUZANNAMJ the below query works fine for me.........SELECT EmailAddress, SubscriberKey
FROM _ListSubscribers
WHERE ListID = '8068829'

Comment: OK - I do not know what a "CONNECT" account is, so not sure I will be able to help further

Comment: @zuzannamj thanks :) No problem.